# ¿Por qué recibo el error "NameError: name 'estimacion' is not defined"?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un script que me permita descifrar un script que decifre un numero entre 1 y 20

Adjunto codigo:

```
import random 
intentoRealizados = 0
numero = random.randint(1,20)

print("Bienvenido Jugador, Cual es tu Nombre")
miNombre = input()

print(miNombre + ",Adivina el numero que estoy pensando entre 1 y 20 , Tienes 6 intentos")

while intentoRealizados > 6:
    print("Intenta adivinar")
    estimacion = input()
    estimacion = int(estimacion)

    intentoRealizados = intentoRealizados + 1

    if estimacion < numero:
        print("Tu estimacion es muy baja")

    if estimacion > numero:
        print("Tu estimacion es muy alta")

    if estimacion ==numero:
        break

if estimacion == numero:
    print("Excelente, " + miNombre+"Adivinaste en solo" + intentoRealizados + "intentos!!!")

if estimacion !=numero:
    print("Se acabaron las opotunidades en numero era, " + numero)
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente error:

> :NameError: name 'estimacion' is not defined

estoy usando a version de python 3.9

Answer (score 2):

La condición

```
while intentoRealizados > 6:
```

debe ser

```
while intentoRealizados < 6:
```

Como la variable parte en cero, la condición del original nunca se cumple. Como nunca entra al cuerpo del `while`, la variable `estimacion` no es evaluada y por tanto, queda indefinida.

También hay unos errores de sintaxis en los `print`: no puedes concatenar cadenas con enteros. Una solución es convertir el entero a cadena usando `str`.

El código completo corregido:

```
import random
intentoRealizados = 0
numero = random.randint(1,20)

print("Bienvenido Jugador, Cual es tu Nombre")
miNombre = input()

print(miNombre + ",Adivina el numero que estoy pensando entre 1 y 20 , Tienes 6 intentos")

while intentoRealizados < 6:
    print("Intenta adivinar")
    estimacion = input()
    estimacion = int(estimacion)

    intentoRealizados = intentoRealizados + 1

    if estimacion < numero:
        print("Tu estimacion es muy baja")

    if estimacion > numero:
        print("Tu estimacion es muy alta")

    if estimacion ==numero:
        break

if estimacion == numero:
    print("Excelente, " + miNombre+"Adivinaste en solo" + str(intentoRealizados) + "intentos!!!")

if estimacion !=numero:
    print("Se acabaron las opotunidades en numero era, " + str(numero))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Funciono perfecto.